# SQL: How do I read this?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have this SQL instruction (given from someone else)

```
FROM P INNER JOIN
C ON P.p1 = C.p1 INNER JOIN
G INNER JOIN
U ON G.u1 = U.u1 ON
C.c1 = G.c1 INNER JOIN
R ON P.r1 = R.r1 INNER JOIN
F ON U.f1 = F.f1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
UN ON U.u1 = UN.u1
```

How do I read all this? How do the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th lines work?

Comment: Read this visual explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html. However, this is a particularly ugly set of joins, and it's very unclear what the intent of them is.

Comment: Are you asking how SQL joins work?

Comment: Asking how this specific instruccion works... but, as someone said in the answers, one of the ON's is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some formatting, I think it becomes easier:

```
FROM P INNER JOIN C 
   ON P.p1 = C.p1 
INNER JOIN G 
INNER JOIN U 
   ON G.u1 = U.u1 
   ON C.c1 = G.c1 
INNER JOIN R 
   ON P.r1 = R.r1 
INNER JOIN F 
   ON U.f1 = F.f1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN UN 
    ON U.u1 = UN.u1
```

And then it looks like one of your ON's is in the wrong place:

```
FROM P INNER JOIN C 
   ON P.p1 = C.p1 
INNER JOIN G 
   **ON C.c1 = G.c1**       
INNER JOIN U        
    ON G.u1 = U.u1
INNER JOIN R 
   ON P.r1 = R.r1 
INNER JOIN F 
   ON U.f1 = F.f1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN UN 
    ON U.u1 = UN.u1
```

Formatting really helps this sort of thing...

Comment: I think you're right... but the results are the same in both cases. Thanks.

Comment: You are asking us how the query you have given works with no table schema or any sort of business logic.  Reading the article @RB gave will be your best bet.